# Create Python dictionary in C

Tags: c

Is it possible to create Python like dictionary in C? I need to have structure that will have key values. I wrote small code in Python that does all needed things(for C code I don't need to worry about input and comparison of the lists):

```
dic = {}

while 1:
        id = raw_input()
        line = raw_input()
        if id in dic.keys():
                dic[id].append(line)
        else:
                dic[id] = []
                dic[id].append(line)
        if len(dic[id]) == 3:
                if all(elem == dic[id][0] for elem in dic[id]):
                        print "Same"
                        dic[id] = []
                else:
                        print "Diffrent"
                        dic[id] = []
```

Is there a way of rewriting this code to C?

Answer (score 3):

GLib has a usable hash table implementation in C:

https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.37/glib-Hash-Tables.html